# how to resolve "The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

Im getting the "The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large" error while im trying to access the save method in wcf using my MVC app, i double checked my web.config everything seemed correct, i have been trying to resolve this since two days , i tried everything that i found on google but i failed, please help me fix this.

this is system.servicemodel in web.config from MVC app (client)

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="IPersonProfileServiceEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="IClientAssessmentEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="ICMSServiceEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICMSService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="IPersonProfileServiceEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="ICMSServiceEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="IClientAssessmentEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://servicetest.iltest.illinois.gov/AGE/PersonProfile/PersonProfileWCFService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IPersonProfileServiceEndpoint" contract="PersonProfileWCFService.IPersonProfileWCFService" name="IPersonProfileServiceEndpoint">
    <identity>
      <dns value="illinois.gov" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:24500/Services/ClientAssessmentService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IClientAssessmentEndpoint" contract="ClientAssessmentWCF.IClientAssessment" name="IClientAssessmentEndpoint" />
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:24500/Services/CMSService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ICMSServiceEndpoint" contract="CMSService.ICMSService" name="ICMSServiceEndpoint" />
</client>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="debug">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<!--<services>
  <service name="TestService" behaviorConfiguration="debug" />
</services>-->
```

below is my system.servicemodel in web.config from wcf Project (server)

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBindingConfig" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />

      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <!--<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfig" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>-->
</bindings>

<services>
  <!--<service name="CMS.WCFApp.Services.CaseManagementService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingConfig" bindingNamespace="http://localhost:24500/Services/CaseManagementService.svc" name="ICaseManagementServiceEndpoint" contract="CMS.WCFApp.ServiceContract.ICaseManagementService">
      --><!--<identity>
        <dns value="illinois.gov"/>
      </identity>-->
    <!--
    </endpoint>
  </service>



  <service name="CMS.WCFApp.Services.ClientAssessmentService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingConfig" bindingNamespace="http://localhost:24500/Services/ClientAssessmentService.svc" name="IClientAssessmentEndpoint" contract="CMS.WCFApp.ServiceContract.IClientAssessment">
      -->
    <!--<identity>
        <dns value="illinois.gov"/>
      </identity>--><!--
    </endpoint>
  </service>-->

  <service name="CMS.WCFApp.Services.CMSService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingConfig" bindingNamespace="http://localhost:24500/Services/CMSService.svc" name="ICMSServiceEndpoint" contract="CMS.WCFApp.ServiceContract.ICMSService">
      <!--<identity>
        <dns value="illinois.gov"/>
      </identity>-->
    </endpoint>
  </service>

  <!--<service name="CMS.WCFApp.Services.CManagementService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingConfig" bindingNamespace="http://localhost:24500/Services/CManagementService.svc" name="ICManagementServiceEndpoint" contract="CMS.WCFApp.ServiceContract.ICManagementService">

  --><!--<identity>
    <dns value="illinois.gov"/>
  </identity>--><!--

    </endpoint>
  </service>-->
</services>
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your `<system.serviceModel>` config?  Chances are you've defined the binding but you don't *assign* the binding, which means you're getting the default values, not your values.  Also, post both the service and client web.configs please.

Answer (score 0):

its a common mistake. i guess its your server side web config. try add the same config to your client and your problem will solve.